# Message: invalid type: null, expected a string at line 1 column 12

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, selenium-webdriver

Есть парсер, но почему - то не работает перелистывание страниц, хотя все должно быть в порядке, просто выбивает ошибку Message: invalid type: null, expected a string at line 1 column 12
Вот есть цикл перелистывания

```
 try:
                a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pager__number-lbl-i')
                url = a_next_page.get_attribute('href')

            except NoSuchElementException:
                break
```

Вот ссылка на сайт с которого нужно спарсить данные:

https://comfy.ua/ua/catalogsearch/result/index/?p=3&q=+Gazer&search_provider=anyquery&strategy=vectors%2Czero_queries_predictor

пробовал 3 css селектора, а именно:

```
 a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pager__number-lbl-i')
 a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.category-next__i')
 a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.category-next')
```

в чем может быть проблема?
Вот строка в которой выбивает ошибку

```
while True:
            print('Load:', url)
            driver.get(url)
```

Вот собственно в чем проблема, все идет хорошо до конца страницы, а потом в ссылке возвращает значение None

```
('Штатна магнітола Gazer CM5509-RB for Hyundai Accent (RB) (2010-2015)', '12 999\n₴\nБонусами\n130 ₴', 'Есть в наличии')
('Штатна магнітола Gazer CM6510-GFW for Mitsubishi Outlander (GFW) (2014-2017)', '17 619\n₴\nБонусами\n176 ₴', 'Есть в наличии')
('-', '-', 'Есть в наличии')
Load: None
```

Выбивает ошибку в 37 строке Message: invalid type: null, expected a string at line 1 column 12

```
Load: None
Message: invalid type: null, expected a string at line 1 column 12

Трассировка стека:
 >  File "C:\Users\К.Бояр (Второй)\source\repos\ParcerComfy\ParcerComfy\ParcerComfy.py", line 37, in parse
 >    driver.get(url)
 >  File "C:\Users\К.Бояр (Второй)\source\repos\ParcerComfy\ParcerComfy\ParcerComfy.py", line 85, in <module> (Current frame)
 >    items = parse(url)
```

Comment: Добавьте полную трассу ошибки, пока непонятно где произошло и как к этому пришло. И добавьте минимальный пример парсера с этой ошибкой

Comment: Сейчас пришлю :)

Comment: Обновил вопрос где пример парсера и в чем собственно суть проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в `url` значение `None`, поэтому тут ошибка:

```
print('Load:', url)
driver.get(url)
```

В логах написано про значение `url`:

```
Load: None
```

Переменная `url` становится `None` тут:

```
try:
    a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pager__number-lbl-i')
    url = a_next_page.get_attribute('href')
except NoSuchElementException:
    break
```

Представьте случай, когда есть тег `a`, но у него нет атрибута/значения `href`, думаю это ваш случай.

##### Решения тут 2:

1. Самый простой. Добавьте в css-селектор условие, что нужен тег с атрибутом `href` ([в прошлом ответе было такое решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1338471/201445)):

   ```
   a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pager__number-lbl-i[href]')
   ```
2. Добавьте условие, что если `url` будет пустой, то `break`:

   ```
   try:
       ...
       url = a_next_page.get_attribute('href')
       if not url:
           break

   except NoSuchElementException:
       break
   ```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Но до проблему это мне не решило, пусть и ошибка не вылезает, программа завершается вот так:
('-', '-', 'Есть в наличии')
Total goods: 52
Saved to Parcer_Comfy_2021-10-19.csv
А там должно быть 400+ товаров и спарсила программа только первую страницу

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII, значит где-то ошиблись, смотрите, разбирайтесь, отлаживайте свой код :)

Comment: Я знаю в чем проблема, у меня неверный css селектор, но я не могу получить селектор или xpath который будет стабильно работать

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII, сделайте вопрос с проблемным парсером, опишите что не так, я посмотрю в течении 5 минут ;)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо вам огромное, сколько раз вы меня уже выручали!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1339808/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bd%d0%b0-selenium

Comment: Добрый день, я понимаю что я вас скорее всего уже заколебал, грубо говоря, но не могли бы глянуть? Я уже +- понял как парсить что бы все работало, но вот что бы пагинация производилась с помощью js и без атрибута href у меня впервые, подскажите пожалуйста что делать
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1340233/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII, добрый день! Хорошо, посмотрю :) Кст, хотите поддержать меня голосуйте за мои ответы и вопросы, что вам кажутся полезными ;) :D

Comment: Хочу :) Обязательно проголосую