# Проблемный парсер на Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Проблема в чем, есть парсер который должен пробегать по всем страницам и собрать наименование, цену и наличие, все работает пока не подходит момент перехода на другую страницу, код переходит на страницу и завершает программу, а если убрать проверку то программа будет бесконечно переходить на вторую страницу, я думаю что проблема в 61-66 строке кода:

```
 try:
                a_next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="categoryList"]/div[3]/div/div/a[2]')
                url = a_next_page.get_attribute('href')
              
            except NoSuchElementException:
                break
```

Вот полный код парсера:
https://replit.com/@Konstantin-Niko/Parcer#ParcerComfy.py

И еще небольшой вопрос, как создать отдельный столбик где будет выводится сегодняшняя дата?

```
def save_goods(
        file_name: Union[str, Path],
        items: List[Tuple[str, str, str]],
        encoding='utf-8'
):
    df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['Name', 'Price', 'Nal'])
    df.to_csv(file_name, encoding=encoding)
```

Comment: Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным, т.е. содержать в себе весь код для запуска

Comment: То, на чем остановился: https://pastebin.com/mRkjkZ6n. Помучился с сайтом и встрял с несколькими проблемами. Первое, сайт просто замусоренный, им неудобно пользоваться, чего стоят его самовольные обновления страницы, дико тормозной, куча запросов на левые сайты, очень долгая полная загрузка, поэтому добавил set_page_load_timeout. Второе, у сайта два элемента пагинации, поэтому при взаимодействии нужно это учитывать, если собираетесь использовать клик. Третье и самое неприятное - капча, причем сайт кривой, поэтому капча иногда ломает верстку и не отображается, видна пустая страница

Comment: Оставил в коде цикл для ручного ввода капчи, чтобы скрипт продолжил работу, но из-за проблемы с версткой капчи не представляется возможным. Насчет самой капчи, она такая, что ее самостоятельно не смог пройти, не знаю в чем проблема, мб сайт замечает, что открыт из селениума (такое возможно) и капча становится непроходимой... Т.е. основная проблема в капче, которая возникает при загрузке сайта, в том числе при переходе на страницы

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!

Comment: А что на счет столбика с датой?

Comment: А что с столбиком с датой?

Comment: Та уже ничего, все в норме, спасибо за то что потратили на меня время! Буду думать что делать с этим сайтом

Comment: Константин Николаевич Бояр II, пожалуйста :)