# Слетают фильтры после перехода по элементу пагинации

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Ребята, почему у меня во время перелистывания страницы первую страницу парсит как надо, потом слетают фильтры и парсит вообще что попало?

```
    Load: 
   https://www.foxtrot.com.ua/uk/searchquery=Gazer&filter=_195_588&pFilter=%2C9501%3D115448&page=1
```

После этой страницы фильтры слетают

```
    Load: https://www.foxtrot.com.ua/uk/search?page=2
```

Вот результат выполнения программы:

```
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM7012-J150H Toyota Prado LC150 HL', '22 392 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM6510-ZD Suzuki Swift (ZD) 2004-2010', '17 592 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM6510-V55', '15 992 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM6509-T5 Volkswagen, Skoda, Seat, 2008-2016', '21 990 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM6008-J150', '8 527 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM5510-CMF для Renault Kadjar (CMF) 2015-2017', '12 719 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM6509-GV Suzuki Grand Vitara (GV) 2015-2017', '8 846 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Null', '-', '-')
Load: https://www.foxtrot.com.ua/uk/search?page=2
('Смартфон SAMSUNG Galaxy S20 FE 8/256GB Dual Sim ZBH Cloud Navy (SM-G780GZBHSEK)', '17 499 ₴', '19 999\n-2 500\n17 499 ₴\nот 730 ₴/мес\nКУПИТЬ')
('Телевизор HISENSE 32A5600F', '6 499 ₴', '6 999\n-500\n6 499 ₴\nот 650 ₴/мес\nКУПИТЬ')
('Стиральная машина SAMSUNG WW60J30G03WDUA', '9 999 ₴', '12 699\n-2 700\n9 999 ₴\nот 1000 ₴/мес\nКУПИТЬ')
('Пылесос ROWENTA RO4811EA', '3 199 ₴', '4 399\n-1 200\n3 199 ₴\nот 320 ₴/мес\nКУПИТЬ')
('', '', '')
```

Вот проблемная функция:

```
def parse(url: str) -> List[Tuple[str, str, str]]:
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')

    items = []

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5.5)
    try:
        while True:
            print('Load:', url)
            driver.get(url)

            for item_el in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".card:last-child"):
                try:
                    name = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.card__title').text
                except:
                    name = ('Null')

                # Не у всех товаров есть цена
                try:
                    price = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.card-price').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    price = '-'

                try:nal = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.card__buttons').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    nal = "-"

                row = name, price, nal
                print(row)
                items.append(row)

            # Если есть кнопка перехода на следующую страницу, то продолжаем цикл, иначе завершаем
            try:
                a_next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search-page-container"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/nav/ul/li[6]/a')
                url = a_next_page.get_attribute('href')

            except NoSuchElementException:
                break
```

Полный код: https://dpaste.org/rL0z

Comment: Судя по тому, что выводит `print('Load:', url)` в `url = a_next_page.get_attribute('href')` там уже была ссылка без параметров фильтрации... Если такое поведение на сайте, то поменяйте стратегию, подставляйте сами номер страницы в ссылку как тут: `https://www.foxtrot.com.ua/uk/searchquery=Gazer&filter=_195_588&pFilter=%2C9501%3D115448&page=1`. Для первой странице можно так не делать, для 2 и далее подставлять. А количество страниц вытащите из элемента пагинации

Comment: Пример алгоритма с подбором максимума страниц в цикле парсера: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/46ad669d6ca9c43605d4a1a9e10c4c9d29083837/html_parsing/get_game_genres/parsers/gameguru_ru.py#L18 (не помню, почему там делал переход по номеру, а не по ссылке, но для вашего случая пример хороший :))

Comment: В общем попытался я вытянуть количество страниц  помощью этого алгоритма, но моих способностей хватило только на то что бы зациклить открытие и парсинг первой страницы бесконечно долго.. :(

Comment: Кст, вот этот сайт нормальный, в отличии от того ... прошлого :)

Comment: Я это понимаю, потому что с Комфи вообще мракобесие было, я его почти победил пока он не забагался и у меня весь скрипт теперь вообще не работает

Comment: Кст, для текущего проверьте ссылку, у меня ваша не стала работать - сразу перенаправляло на ru-версию https://www.foxtrot.com.ua/ru с страницей 404. Скорее всего, у вас подобное будет для ссылки из ответа

Comment: Да, я тоже это заметил и поменял ссылку, сейчас все супер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пагинация сделана через проход по страницам, а номер конечной страницы определяется/обновляется на каждой итерации.

Сильно облегчает работу то, что количество страниц есть в атрибуте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример:

```
import datetime as DT
import time

from typing import List, Tuple, Union
from pathlib import Path

# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


def get_text_by_css(parent, css_selector: str, default: str) -> str:
    try:
        return parent.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector).text
    except:
        return default


def parse(url_search: str) -> List[Tuple[str, str, str]]:
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')

    items = []

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5.5)

    try:
        page = last_page = 1
        while page <= last_page:
            url = url_search
            if page > 1:
                url = f'{url_search}&page={page}'

            print(f'Load: {url}')
            driver.get(url)

            for item_el in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".card[data-url]"):
                name = get_text_by_css(item_el, '.card__title', 'Null')
                price = get_text_by_css(item_el, '.card-price', '-')
                nal = get_text_by_css(item_el, '.card__buttons', '-')

                row = name, price, nal
                print(row)

                items.append(row)

            # Обновление номера последней страницы
            try:
                pages_count_el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('*[data-pages-count]')
                last_page = int(pages_count_el.get_attribute('data-pages-count'))

            except NoSuchElementException:
                break

            page += 1

    finally:
        driver.quit()

    return items



def save_goods(
        file_name: Union[str, Path],
        items: List[Tuple[str, str, str]],
        encoding='utf-8'
):
    df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['Name', 'Price', 'Nal'])
    df.to_csv(file_name, encoding=encoding)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.foxtrot.com.ua/ru/search?query=gazer&filter=_195_588"
    items = parse(url)
    print(f'Total goods: {len(items)}')

    file_name = f'foxtrot_parser_{DT.datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d}.csv'
    print(f'Saved to {file_name}')
    save_goods(file_name, items)
```

[Результат в .csv](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/57a412afc5ad582530e8d872c03d6268e388d821/html_parsing/foxtrot_com_ua__ru__search/foxtrot_parser_2021-10-21.csv)